# NextJs Authentication with Next-Auth against DRF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I have an exiting Django project that I am trying to move from templates to NextJs frontend. I came across Next-Auth-js which seems to be nice in Next Auth.

However, the doc seems to focus more with JS related Backend Auth. Following this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-next-auth) I have sent the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable to my DRF Endpoint localhost:8002. While the frontend runs on localhost:3000. While my _app.js looks like this:

```
<Provider options={{site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,}} session={pageProps.session}  >
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</Provider>
```

Using the [Nav.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-next-auth/components/nav.js) for a test, I changed the signin/out href to point to my Django endpoints but it seems next-auth-js ignores this and places a session fetch to my frontend `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session` instead of the the `http://localhost:8002/api/auth/session`.

I will appreciate any assistance on how I can correctly/securely implement this authentication using Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Comment: what is the value for NEXTAUTH_URL?

Comment: NEXTAUTH_URL=https://localhost:8002/api/account/auth/login/     in .env

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [that is the way it should work](https://next-auth.js.org/faq#can-i-use-nextauthjs-with-a-website-that-does-not-use-nextjs), your nextjs site would be a kind of proxy/middleware to your django API `client -> nextjs -> DRF`, you should let it handle the sessions and for any action you need to do in your API for any authentication step, put code to hit those endpoints in the [callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) or [events](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events) configuration, I think [this tutorial](https://arunoda.me/blog/add-auth-support-to-a-next-js-app-with-a-custom-backend) is more accurate for your use case

from the [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials#example)

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```js
import Providers from `next-auth/providers`
...
providers: [
  Providers.Credentials({
    // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
    name: 'Credentials',
    // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
    // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
    // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
      // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
      const user = { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }

      if (user) {
        // call your DRF sign in endpoint here
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
        return Promise.resolve(user)
      } else {
        // If you return null or false then the credentials will be rejected
        return Promise.resolve(null)
        // You can also Reject this callback with an Error or with a URL:
        // return Promise.reject(new Error('error message')) // Redirect to error page
        // return Promise.reject('/path/to/redirect')        // Redirect to a URL
      }
    }
  })
]

...

  events: {
    signOut: async (message) => { /* call your DRF sign out endpoint here */ },
  }
```

Comment: I have visited that tutorial b4 it doesn't relate to my case. I am using Providers.Credentials with existing login/logout endpoints (DRF), and have created custom login.tsx that is supposed to use next-auth signIn() for login.

Comment: @Paullo I don't see how it is not related, you should not expect the calls to be made to DRF, you should call those endpoints yourself in `Provider.Credentials` authorize method and `signOut` event

Comment: I have passed those stages, but finding out this is an existing issue if you follow this discussion https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/280. That discussion thread few others is helping though.

Comment: @Paullo would be nice if you update your question with the new progress you have

Answer (score 3):

You can use `callbacks` here. https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks

```
callbacks: {
  async signIn(user, account, profile) {
    return true
  },
  async redirect(url, baseUrl) {
    return baseUrl
  },
  async session(session, user) {
    return session
  },
  async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
    return token
  }
}
```

in `signIn` callback, you can get accessToken and `tokenId` from provider login. Here, call your DRF API and pass those tokens to your DRF and when you get back the `access_token` and `refresh_token` from DRF. Add them to your user instance. And then in `JWT` callback, get the `access` and `refresh` from `user` and add them into `token`

Got this from some blog

[image]

Though, you also need to handle the refresh token.